# Create batch file to activate Office 2016

Tags: batch

I use below script to activate our Office 2016. Is there any way to combine key and activate in one line so interaction is needed when running the batch.

```
pushd %programfiles%\Microsoft Office\Office16

Echo Activate Office 2016 (64 bit)
echo. =================================
set /p key="Input Office 2016 KEY : "
echo. =================================


cscript ospp.vbs /inpkey:%key%
cscript ospp.vbs /act

@exit /b

popd
```

Comment: You mean to use the key-value instead of asking for it? If so, just include it inside the command.

Comment: Can I use  cscript ospp.vbs /inpkey:%key% /act   (just one commandline instead of two lines)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To include the key in the script, use a command such as:

```
set key=Office-2016-key-string
set "key=Office-2016-key-string"
```

According to Microsoft's article
[Tools to manage volume activation of Office](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/deployoffice/vlactivation/tools-to-manage-volume-activation-of-office),
the syntax is:

```
cscript ospp.vbs [Option:Value] [ComputerName] [User] [Password]
```

So only one option can be used on the command-line.

Comment: Understood one option per line.Thanks a lot